# How to make CPU profiling for a NodeJS native addon written in C++?

Tags: c++, node.js, profiling

I wrote a native addon in C++ for NodeJS and now I need to do some CPU profiling. I tried to use the `--prof` option, but it only shows profiling information about v8 code and nothing about my C++ code. My C++ code also runs in the libuv thread pool used by NodeJS and this is the most important part for which I need CPU profiling... How do I do that? Thanks in advance!